# Oracle SQL select greatest value of the result of two different select statements

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

I'm running select statements in a loop with a cursor to collect data from different tables;
Quick (NOT WORKING) example;

```
select DISTINCT(ordernr) from orders 

INSERT INTO newtable (select Crs.ordernr as ordernr, value1 as value from table2 where table2.ordernr = Crs.ordernr );
INSERT INTO newtable (select Crs.ordernr as ordernr, value2 as value from table3 where tabel3.ordernr=Crs.ordernr ;

)
LOOP
END LOOP;
END;
```

What I could like is just one insert statement which insert just the biggest value of boths select statements.
I've tried to work with greatest function in my loop but i'm running stuck. Both datatypes are the same for value1 and value2

```
insert into newtable(select crs.ordernr as ordernr, greatest
(
select value1 as value from table1 where condition=1, select value2 as value from table2 where condition=1)
)
);
```

Is it possible with a select case or other way to return only one value based on conditions? For example the biggest value of value1 or value2?

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function, it's a _set quantifer_. Skip those extra parentheses and simply write `select DISTINCT ordernr  from ...` to make code clearer.

Comment: Kindly provide sample data along with desired output

Comment: You may find that there is a better solution that lets you eliminate the cursor loops and do it all in a single SQL statement (which will be much faster as it will not context-switch from PL/SQL to SQL and will generate much less redo logs); however, you have not told us what you the overall problem is and we are left trying to solve the narrow problem in the question and not the complete problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `greatest` function and provide subqueries to it, but - follow the syntax, i.e. enclose each of them (`select` statements) into its own parenthesis.

Something like this:

```
SQL> select greatest (  (select max(sal) from emp where job = 'CLERK'),
  2                     (select max(sal) from emp where job = 'ANALYST')
  3                  ) greatest_salary
  4  from dual;

GREATEST_SALARY
---------------
           3450

SQL>
```

---

I have no idea what is this:

```
insert into newtable(select crs.ordernr as ordernr
                     -----------------------------
```

supposed to do; what is `crs`? Where's the `from` clause?

Comment: Thank you, I see there was some code missing, the crs is cursor which is used within a loop. But the solution you proposed works. I just needed to enclose each select statements into its own parenthesis.

Comment: Aha, a cursor. OK, you're welcome, I'm glad if it helped.

Answer (score 1):

From Oracle 12, you can use:

```sql
INSERT INTO newtable (ordernr, value)
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT Crs.ordernr as ordernr,
         value1      as value
  FROM   table2
  WHERE  table2.ordernr = Crs.ordernr
UNION ALL
  SELECT Crs.ordernr,
         value2
  FROM   table3
  WHERE  table3.ordernr=Crs.ordernr
)
ORDER BY value DESC
FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY;
```

This will mean that if you extend the query to extract more columns and you want the highest of one column and the corresponding values of the other columns then the values will all come from that one row with the highest value.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=e45cf4c3513771e384a26aff5ad13236)*

Comment: Thank you for your reaction. I think this could work also, but the first solution looks more simple and readable.

Comment: @Dreqnoid That depends on whether you are getting a single value from each table or multiple values; the answer you have accepted works for a single value but will have difficulties ensuring multiple values are correlated to all come from the same row.

Comment: thank you for clarifying your solution. In my case I alwasy have a single value from each table, but it's good to know this solution as well!